# Custom JS function is not defined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one js function called `ShwoDialog()` which is in search.js file. when i am running my apps then i am getting error message by firefox `ReferenceError: ShwoDialog is not defined`

i though may be i am calling function `ShwoDialog()` before loading the js file called search.js where function is defined. so i saw the html source and found that `ShwoDialog()`  is calling after search.js file is loading.

### here is one small snap of my source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/BlockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Search.js"></script>

<script language='javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function () { ShwoDialog(); });
</script>
</form>
```

i guess may be all the above js is loading when my ShwoDialog() function is calling. is there any way to ensure that i will only call my function just after completion of loading of my search.js file. is any technique is possible then please discuss with me. thanks

### update

i try to do the things in this way but still no luck

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fireWhenReady() {
    if (typeof function1 != 'undefined') {
        function1();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(fireWhenReady, 100);
    }
}
$(document).ready(fireWhenReady);
</script>
```

### MY ShowDialog full code

```
function ShowDialog() {
        $("#SrchDialog")
        .html('<div class="Srchloading"></div>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                bgiframe: true,
                height: 542,
                width: 314,
                modal: false,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: false,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 600
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 500
                },
                open: function (type, data) {
                    //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                    $(this).parent().appendTo('.g8');

                    var t = $(this).parent(), w = window;
                    t.offset({
                        top: (($(window).height() - 542) / 2),
                        left: (($(window).width() - 314) / 2)
                    });
                },
                close: function () {
                    //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
            });


        $("#SrchDialog").load('SearchFeedback.aspx', function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
            if (statusTxt == "success") {
                sHtml = responseTxt;
                sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#SrchExtract').html();
                $sHtml = $(sHtml);
                $("#SrchDialog").html(sHtml);
                $("#SrchDialog").dialog('open').show();
                BindEvent();
            }

            if (statusTxt == "error") {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });

    }

    function BindEvent() {
        $("input[id*='btnsrchSubmit']").live("click", function () {
            alert('send');
            return false;
        });

        $("#imgSrchclose").live("click", function () {
            $("#SrchDialog").closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
            return false;
        });
    }
```

ShowDialog code as given which is defined in search.js file. when i am calling `ShowDialog` function on button click then it works fine but when i call at the bottom of the page then i am getting error called function undefined. please tell me what is wrong in my `ShowDialog` function and how to solve it.

Comment: Typo? Should be `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Well, he wrote it like that 5 times.... maybe it is not a typo!

Comment: are you willing to write ShowDialog instead of ShwoDialog ?;)

Comment: that is not typo...i just gave that name

Comment: does that mean it solved the problem?

Comment: May be search.js has some error. Just see debugger if search.js is loading.

Comment: Would you be able to add a snippet of the code where the function is defined? It might be a scope issue.

Comment: `</form>`?? where is starting tag? LOL

Comment: i did not include that begining form tag

Comment: ShowDialog code added....so please tell me where i am making the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/BlockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Search.js"></script>

<script language='javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function () { ShwoDialog(); });
</script>
```

Javascript will be processed in serial order, so it should even work without `docuemnt.ready` if your function is not using `DOM`.

first `blockui.js` will be loaded, run. then `jquery` is loaded and run, thus it goes in serial order and you are all good.

1. This can get interrupted if some error occurs anywhere in code, then nothing after that will be processed. Check your console for errors.
2. Also if `search.js` fails to load obviously the function will remain undefined. Check and ensure that `searchjs` is loaded, use network tab in chrome dev tools or the counterpart in firefox/ie.
3. As @joe mentioned, it can even be a scope issue.
4. Have you included `jquery` before using all these jquery plugins?

Comment: Fix the typos in your question please, its confusing. Your function is named `ShowDialog` and error is `ShwoDialog` is not defined. Please copy paste everything in correct spelling.

Comment: check the fourth point as well, i dont see jquery included in your source. Also make sure its included first.

Comment: i am including the jquery file before search.js. i check it with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

First try and see if every javascript is actually loaded, than please delete the call to the function and check if there are some other errors in the console. Also there is no need for you to use the document ready when you call the javascript in this order.

Comment: Can you please move all your javascript right before the closing body tag. I mean all loading js files and custome javascript that was written. So basicly add: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/BlockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Search.js"></script>

<script language='javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function () { ShwoDialog(); });
</script>` before your closing body tag